# How can I make functions in a COM object with two dimensional arrays visible in Agilent VEE?

Tags: c#, arrays, com

I have a COM object (C#, visual studio) with a function that takes a two dimensional array as an in parameter. When I want to access this function via Agilent VEE is is not visible in the Function & Objects browser, and not accessible. If I change the array to be single dimension, is becomes visible right away.

I have heard that VEE is not good for dealing with two dimensional arrays, but there should be a workaround.

Anyone that knows anything about making com objects with two dimensional arrays visible from vee?
Best regards, 
AK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM Automation supports SafeArray as the wrapper type for arrays.  The CLR interop layer for COM automatically generates them from a C# array type.  But they are equivalent to multi-dimensional arrays, not jagged arrays.  There is no equivalent automation type for arrays-of-arrays, they'll be exposed as a single dimensional array of variants where each variant is an array.

Enough to trip up a COM client, perhaps, the syntax gets hairy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it, of course two minutes after posting a question. 
I declared my arrays as jagged arrays,

`int [][] array = new [][];`and changed it to`int[,] array = new int [,];`

Now it works!